# Why does Eclipse sometimes warn about arrays of arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, eclipse

In Eclipse, the following line of JavaScript

```
var a1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
```

generates the warnings:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Number[] to any
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Number[] to any
```

while

```
var a2 = [['w', 'x'], ['y', 'z']];
```

generates:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to any
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to any
```

and

```
var a3 = [[1, 2], ['y', 'z']];
```

generates:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Number[] to any
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to any
```

However, these lines are all okay:

```
var a4 = [[1, 'x'], [3, 'y']];
var a5 = [[1, 2]];
var a6 = [['x', 'y']];
```

There seems to be a problem with arrays of arrays, when the sub-arrays contain the same primitive type. However, I don't understand why, and the code seems to execute okay. Can someone explain what Eclipse is worried about?

Comment: Just my .02$ on the subject but the eclipse Javascript engine is a bit pissy about things.  Might just be a quirk in its operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a bug.  There is essentially no such thing as a type mismatch in Javascript.

I would hazard a  guess that the parser that is doing this was based on a Java parser, and this is a bit of that original parser peeking through.

Comment: [Here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351345) is an example of a similar bug in eclipse.

Comment: Yes, I think you must be right. There are some other rather dubious warnings too, such as "var i; for (i in obj)" giving "the local variable i may not have been initialized".

Answer (score 0):

The javascript validators in eclipse can filter these out in preferences.