# java warning (?) showing up for javascript code in eclipse (juno)

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I've got a javascript file (.js) that I'm editing in Eclipse (Juno). It's giving me this warning:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Number to ___anonymous6554_6555
```

on the return line of this code (this is a simplified example, but it still shows the error):

```
function foo() {
    var temp = {};
    if (true) {
        temp = 1;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

If I change it to:

```
function foo() {
    var temp = new Object();
    if (true) {
        temp = 1;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

the warning goes away, but then jsHint warns me to use object literal notation. Grrr...

Any ideas where that might be coming from? The warning looks like a java warning to me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

This is Eclipse's fault. Take a look at this similar question: [Why does Eclipse sometimes warn about arrays of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978429/why-does-eclipse-sometimes-warn-about-arrays-of-arrays-in-javascript)

I'd ignore the warning (the Java warning), and use `{}`.